# $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$. Show there's $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$

How can I show there's $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$.

I know it's true since the values of f(x) for large enough x are close to 0 as much as I want. So, that means that the same value would have to appear at least twice, and then it can be concluded. However, I don't know how to show it formally.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128690/prove-there-exists-a-in-bbbr-such-that-fa-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f$ is identically zero there isn't much to show.

If $f(x_1) > 0$ for some $x_1$, you can use the limit to deduce there is $M > 0$ for which $$x \ge M \implies |f(x)| < \dfrac{f(x_1)}{2}.$$

The function $f$ has a maximum on the interval $[0,M]$, and it doesn't occur at either endpoint since $f(x_1)$ exceeds both $f(0)$ and $f(M)$.

The derivative vanishes at this maximum.

If $f(x_1) < 0$ for some $x_1$ you can argue similarly.

Comment: How can you explain formally that there's a maximum? Do you use weierstrass theorem? @Umberto P.

Comment: That is one of the basic facts of calculus: a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval attains a maximum value.

Comment: @GADI look at `extreme value theorem`

Comment: @UmbertoP. But the domain isn't a closed or bounded interval.  Nonetheless the image is bounded, and there must be a supremum and and infimum and the rest of your argument follows.

Comment: @DougM please read the answer more carefully.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I was commenting on your comment. "a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval...."  The domain isn't closed and bounded.

Comment: @DougM The answer asserts "$f$ has a maximum on the interval $[0,M]$"

Comment: @UmbertoP. I agree with everything in the answer.  It is only your comment that I was trying to carify.

Comment: You can also argue that there are $f(0)<f(x_0)/2$, $f(x_0)>f(x_0)/2$, and $f(M)<f(x_0)/2$, so there are points $x_1\in (0,x_0)$ and $x_2\in(x_0,M)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_0)/2$, by continuity. Then you can apply Rolle's theorem, as was your original plan, AFAICT.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen: Or one can map $[0,\infty)$ to a compact interval and apply Rolle's theorem there, say $g(x)=f(\tan x)$ for $0 \le x < \pi/2$ and $g(\pi/2)=0$ (so that $g$ becomes continuous on $[0,\pi/2]$).