# Problem about differentiation. Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function twice differentiable such that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}f'(x) = A$. Prove that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f''(c) = 0$.

I tried supose that $f''(c) \neq 0$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f'$ has no minimum and maximum. Can I say that $f'$ is increasing or decreasing? If yes, this is contrary to the hypothesis. If not, I would like suggestions.

Comment: Is $f''$ continuous?

Comment: is not one of the hypothesis

Comment: Apply this one to the function $f'$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128690/prove-there-exists-a-in-bbbr-such-that-fa-0

Answer (score 2):

**Incomplete answer**: I need the continuity of $f''$.

Consider the function $g(x)=f'(x)-f'(-x)$. This function is odd and
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=0$$

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $g(0)=0$ and $g$ is continuous, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)|<\epsilon$ if $|x|<\delta$. Let $\epsilon_1=|g(\delta/2)|$. There exists some $K>\delta$ such that $|g(x)|<\epsilon_1$ if $x>K$. Let $\epsilon_2=g(K+1)$. By continuity and the fact that $g$ is odd, there is some $\delta_1\in(0,\delta/2)$ such that $g(\delta_1)=g(K+1)$ or $g(-\delta_1)=g(K+1)$.

Now, by Rolle's theorem, there is some $c\in(-\delta_1,K+1)$ such that $g'(c)=0$. That is,
$$f''(c)+f''(-c)=0$$

Again by continuity, there is some $c_1\in(-c,c)$ such that $f''(c_1)=0$.

Comment: I can't help using the continuity of $f''$, but I have the feeling that this is the way. Any ideas to avoid this problem?

Comment: The Darboux theorem. This result doesn't require the continuity of $f''$. I think this solves.

Comment: @LucasCorreaLopes How do you prove that $c_1$ exists if $f''$ is not continuous? Does a derivative meet Darboux theorem even if it is not continuous?

Comment: The function $f'$ is differentiable in $[-\delta_{1}, K + 1]$. Since $f''(c) + f''(-c) = 0$, we can assume that $f''(-c) < 0 < f''(c)$, then exist $d \in (-\delta_{1}, K + 1)$ such that $f''(d) = 0$. 

The Darboux theorem: "Let $f: [a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable em $[a, b]$. If $f'(a) < d < f'(b)$, then existe $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = d$", doesn't required continuity.

Answer (score 2):

If $f'$ is constant then we are done. Otherwise there is a value, say $B=f'(b) $, of $f'$ which is different from $A$ and let's assume that $B>A$ (the case $B<A$ is similar). Choose any number $C$ between $A$ and $B$ and then by the given limiting conditions we can ensure that there is a number $N>|b|$ such that $f'(x) < C$ whenever $x\leq -N$ or $x\leq N$.

Now $f'$ is continuous on $[-N, N] $ and hence attains its maximum value in this intervals. Since $b\in(-N, N) $ and $f'(b) =B>C$ it follows that this maximum value is attained at an interior point $c\in(-N, N) $. By usual principle of maxima/minima we have $f''(c) =0$.